# Make overlay fade out slowly?

Tags: css

I'm currently editing a subreddit on reddit.com and my methods are restricted on **CSS only**.
I managed to get a overlay effect when you hover over the menu on the left side. It's fading in, but I don't know how to fade it out. Since *transition wasn't working* I tried another method with an animation.

**TL;DR:** Overlay fade in: yes - fade out: no :(

Here are some parts of the code I used:

```
#sr-header-area .drop-choices:hover:before {
   content: "";
   font-size: 13px;
   display: block;
   position: fixed !important;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin-left: 300px;
   pointer-events: none;
   z-index: 700 !important;
   animation: fade 0.5s ease;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;}

@keyframes fade {
   0% {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}
   100% {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);}}
```

Maybe someone can help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this effect with transitions and that would be the way I'd personally recommend. Heres a quick implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/z1c8bvcd/1/

The main thing to remember is that you need to define the CSS properties that the div will return to once the hover state is no longer in effect, not just what they look like when hovered otherwise the :before pseudo element will be removed from the DOM.

```
#foo:before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  transition: background 0.5s, margin-left 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed!important;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#foo:hover:before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin-left: 300px;
}
```

I think you can also achieve a similar effect using keyframes, but I think the animation would run once when the page loads and then whenever the div is hovered.